# Introduce sequential strings after every n lines using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

Let's say I have a file looking like this

```
>id_1
FHGTHEGTYUUSHGGTW
DJGAODSIOAJHGIUHASIGA
LKHAGNAGNSGASGA
LHA;GJBL;JA
LAHGUBNKNOHOIHAGAS
>id_2
F;AHGAUBIFAGGA
lslgohgihianvhijhag
kaigih;AGHIASNGIASGIA
ALKBGIH;ohgihaighg
```

Output I am expecting should have a unique sequential id after every two lines

```
>id_1_1
FHGTHEGTYUUSHGGTW
DJGAODSIOAJHGIUHASIGA
>id_1_2
LKHAGNAGNSGASGA
LHA;GJBL;JA
>id_1_3
LAHGUBNKNOHOIHAGAS
>id_2_1
F;AHGAUBIFAGGA
lslgohgihianvhijhag
>id_2_2
kaigih;AGHIASNGIASGIA
ALKBGIH;ohgihaighg
```

I have used `sed` for simple replacements but not something this complex. I am not familiar with `awk` at all. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I generally include code showing my effort but I was just stuck in this case. Will try my best next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> cat test.awk
BEGIN {n=2}
/^>id/ { title = $0; c=0; next }
(++c%n == 1) { print title "_" int(c/n+1) }
{print}
```

Every 1st, 3rd, etc line of each part, we first print the custom title, while we reset at every new title (without printing, notice the `next`) and we print every line.

Edit: I made `n` configurable, so for `n=3` it will print title every 1st, 4th, 7th line and so on.

n=2

```
> awk -f test.awk file
>id_1_1
FHGTHEGTYUUSHGGTW
DJGAODSIOAJHGIUHASIGA
>id_1_2
LKHAGNAGNSGASGA
LHA;GJBL;JA
>id_1_3
LAHGUBNKNOHOIHAGAS
>id_2_1
F;AHGAUBIFAGGA
lslgohgihianvhijhag
>id_2_2
kaigih;AGHIASNGIASGIA
ALKBGIH;ohgihaighg
```

n=3

```
> awk -f test.awk file
>id_1_1
FHGTHEGTYUUSHGGTW
DJGAODSIOAJHGIUHASIGA
LKHAGNAGNSGASGA
>id_1_2
LHA;GJBL;JA
LAHGUBNKNOHOIHAGAS
>id_2_1
F;AHGAUBIFAGGA
lslgohgihianvhijhag
kaigih;AGHIASNGIASGIA
>id_2_2
ALKBGIH;ohgihaighg
```

Comment: this looks good and it works for me, however, just for my learning, how would I change the number of lines? I tried playing with it changing numbers but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be solved in many ways. The questioner declares that he does not know AWK at all, which is why I present a somewhat lengthy solution instead, very simple to understand without any AWK idioms.

**The script can be easily modified for any value of n and partition pattern.**

To use a different split from the sample 2 just change n in the BEGIN section.
Changing the split pattern is also easy. It is enough to change the RS to the new pattern and sets new freely chosen prefix.

script file.awk:

```
BEGIN {
n=2
RS=">id_[0-9]*"
prefix=">id_"
}
// {
j=1
for (i=1;i<=NF;i=i+n){
  print(prefix NR-1"_"j)
  for(k=0;k<n;k++) {
    if ($(i+k)) {print $(i+k)}
  }
  j++
}
i=1
}
```

call:

```
gawk -f file.awk  file
```

GNU AWK must be used because of the regular expression in RS.

Result:

```
>id_1_1
FHGTHEGTYUUSHGGTW
DJGAODSIOAJHGIUHASIGA
>id_1_2
LKHAGNAGNSGASGA
LHA;GJBL;JA
>id_1_3
LAHGUBNKNOHOIHAGAS
>id_2_1
F;AHGAUBIFAGGA
lslgohgihianvhijhag
>id_2_2
kaigih;AGHIASNGIASGIA
ALKBGIH;ohgihaighg
```

Explanation AWK built-in variables:

```
RS sets the record separator
NF is the number of fields in the record
NR number of records loaded
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.